# /give command in 1.5.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am playing a world in 1.5.2 and I need to know how to give myself an item with a high level of unbreaking. Does anybody know how to do this with /give?

I need an answer compatible with version 1.5.2 please.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot do this with `/give` in 1.5.2 because the dataTag argument was added in 1.7.2.

You can use [`/enchant`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#enchant) instead, which was added in 1.4.4. However, it restricts both what can be applied on an item as well as the level of enchantment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give yourself an item with an enchantment using the **/give** command.

However, you can get enchanting books and an anvil (if you're in creative) then combine your tool with the book or use the **/enchant** command (faster than the anvil and books method in survival.)

Answer (score 0):

You cant enchant over the highest level.If you look in the enchanting books you can find the highest level of enchantment.
But look in creative because if you look in survival you will find the highest and the lowest.

Comment: Command blocks and mods are the only way to get over the max level

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: THIS WORKS WITH 1.15.2**

This is simple to do, but it only works in Java Edition. Use: /give @s ItemName{Enchantments:[{id:unbreaking,lvl:(Whatever Needed Level)}]} 1, or you could just make it unbreakable with: /give @s Itemname{Unbreakable:1} 1. Also, if you need to learn how to use the basics of /give, check out this video: